# Xamarin.Forms: Waze maps instead of Xamarin.Forms.Maps?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, waze

This may be a dumb question, but here goes.

I have a simple app that plots points in a `Xamarin.Forms.Map`. My `MainPage.xaml` looks like this and it works as expected:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Maps"
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GasStations"
                 x:Class="GasStations.MainPage">
</ContentPage>
```

Instead of using this map, I would like to display the map from the `Waze` app.

Is it as easy as switching the control or is it more complex?

Comment: If you are a part of their Broadcasters' program you can embed Waze via HTML IFrames on a browser-based "website" (but not within your own mobile device), they also also certain data feeds and they have an SDK for transportation companies, again these are program-based. What is available is deep-linking so your app can open the Waze app and do things like Search, Nagivate, Show, etc... but again that is within their app, not yours... https://developers.google.com/waze/deeplinks/

Comment: So the Waze map control is not like Xamarin.Forms.Map, that can be used in mobile apps? Is it proprietary of Microsoft?

Comment: It is not a control, it is an app. And not Microsoft, Google owns Waze.